# Whats the difference between these two implementations of a Ruby function?

Tags: ruby, loops

1)

```
require 'sqlite3'

db = SQLite3::Database.new('development.sqlite3')
db.results_as_hash = true;


rows = db.execute(" SELECT * FROM listings WHERE name = '' OR telephone = '' OR latitude = '' OR longitude = '' ")

rows do |row|

  id_num = row['id']
  puts "Id = #{id_num}"

  dupe_name = row['name']
  puts "name = #{dupe_name}"

  dupe_tel = row['telephone']
  puts "tel = #{dupe_tel}"

  dupe_lat = row['latitude']
  puts "lat = #{dupe_lat}" 

  dupe_long = row['longitude']
  puts "lat = #{dupe_long}" 
  puts '===end===='



end
```

2)

```
    require 'sqlite3'

db = SQLite3::Database.new('development.sqlite3')
db.results_as_hash = true;


db.execute(" SELECT * FROM listings WHERE name = '' OR telephone = '' OR latitude = '' OR longitude = '' ") do |row|

  id_num = row['id']
  puts "Id = #{id_num}"

  dupe_name = row['name']
  puts "name = #{dupe_name}"

  dupe_tel = row['telephone']
  puts "tel = #{dupe_tel}"

  dupe_lat = row['latitude']
  puts "lat = #{dupe_lat}" 

  dupe_long = row['longitude']
  puts "lat = #{dupe_long}" 
  puts '===end===='



end
```

The 2nd one works and the 1st one does not.

Why is that so? Doesn't the `db.execute` function return a result set. If so why cant you loop through it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried changing `rows do |row|` to `rows.each do |row|` for the first function?.

With the first one you get a collection and assign it to `rows`. You need to create a iterator for rows after that to loop trough the collection.

The second function, .[execute](http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/sqlite3/classes/SQLite3/Database.html#M000103) already returns a iterator.

[More on Iterators](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html#UD)